# Proving a statement using Hilbert's axioms and rules of inference for propositional logic

Tags: logic, axioms

I want to prove the following statement: 
[image]

using Hillbert's axioms sand rules of inference for propositional logic.
I am having trouble doing so.
It seems just like the transitive statment, can I prove it using MP ?

Edit: These are the Hillbert's axioms : 
4[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please give a reference for the set of axioms and rules of inference that you want to use.

Comment: It is quite easy if you have already proved the *Deduction Theorem*.

Comment: As the whole point of Hilbert's axioms is to establish the deduction theorem, you shouldn't even begin this problem until you are familiar with DT and it's proof.

Comment: I've edited my question and added axioms and rules of inference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) $A \to B$ --- premise

(2) $B \to C$ --- premise

(3) $\vdash (B \to C) \to (A \to (B \to C))$ --- Ax.1

(4) $A \to (B \to C)$ --- from (2) and (3) by *Modus Ponens*

(5) $\vdash (A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to B) \to (A \to C))$ --- Ax.2

(6) $(A \to B) \to (A \to C)$ --- from (4) and (5) by *Modus Ponens*

> (7) $A \to C$ --- from (1) and (6) by *Modus Ponens*.

Thus, with (1), (2) and (6), we have :

> $A \to B, B \to C \vdash A \to C$.

With two applications of the *Deduction Theorem*, we have :

> > $\vdash (A \to B) \to (( B \to C) \to (A \to C))$.